# Problems including PDB files in Visual Studio 2010 Installer project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I am having a hard time tracking down how to include the debug symbol files in an install project for the debug build (only).  If I Project -> Add -> Output -> Debug Symbols (for each project), it will include them when running the release build of the installer.

I want the installer project to only include debug files for the projects I specified when installing the debug build of the installer and not for the release.

Any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by Visual Studio setup projects. Other setup authoring tools offer this feature as *builds* or *releases*. Basically, multiple builds with different content.